# Ubuntu server 9.10 freezes up after ~10 minutes - unconventional

Tags: ubuntu

There is a topic by essentially the same name, but my answer leads to another question which I would like answered so... My case is as follows:

I connect through SSH to my server... no problems for many months on Ubuntu Server 9.04. Eventually I decided to updgrade and straight away I get the 10 minutes freeze problem. I went through all the possible fixes (many can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/80520/ubuntu-server-9-10-freezes-up-after-10-minutes) but my quick fix, the only that worked, leaves me with no real answer as to why and how to properly correct it...

As ridiculous as it sounds... while I leave a keyboard plugged in... it runs without flaw.

Can anyone make sense of this?

For the sake of completeness, (although none of the following made any difference upon subsequent completion), some of the permanent changes I have made while trying to correct the issue are: replacing samba config file with 9.04 backup, booting with noapic and modifying sysctl.conf, just uncommenting additional settings for enhanced security.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to look through your /var/log/syslog, and share it with us ;)

Comment: I've had this happen to me, especially with a flaky KVM. The solution was to plug a keyboard in to it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without additional info.

To narrow down the issue: Please provide the end of /var/log/syslog, there may be something in there.

Also, in case the system crashes so hard that even /var/log/syslog can not be written, try switching to a virtual console if in X, and leave it running until it hangs. Any kernel trouble should also be printed to a virtual console.

Comment: Ok, before I post more... this strikes me as possibly relevant to the keyboard... I managed to recreate the freeze by unplugging the keyboard again and rebooting... but upon checking the last entries of the syslog... well, the last entry to be exact... 

Do you think the following could point to the cause?

Comment: Nov 26 23:56:09 server console-kit-daemon[616]: WARNING: Couldn't read /proc/599/environ: Failed to open file '/proc/599/environ': No such file or directory

Comment: A few other points, X is not installed and I have never, (until this issue,) used a peripheral or monitor on this box since it's initial install.

Comment: Ok, it now froze with the keyboard... looking back I'm wondering why I didn't let sleeping dogs lie... Here was the last entry in the log this time.. nearly 10 minutes after the previous entries:                Nov 27 00:17:01 server CRON[1986]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Comment: Sorry, these log entries all look perfectly normal. No clue really...