# Ubuntu Server 10.04 Lucid Lynx stops responding at exactly 10 minutes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dell

I'm running ubuntu server lucid on a Dell Dimension 3000. I'm running headless and when I have a display plugged into the VGA, it's fine, so it must have something to do with the display drivers. When SSH'd in I run htop and at EXACTLY 10:01 uptime, it stops responding. Nothing interesting in /var/log/messages. It's upgraded from 9.10.

Has anyone had this issue or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling from scratch. The server's been running for 14 minutes headless now. Not the best solution, but hey.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be related to the linux console screen blanking, but this is just a guess.  Like it's trying to blank the screen and triggering something that causes a lockup when doing it without an attached monitor.  Or maybe when activating powersaving on that screen.

Try this and see if it makes a difference.

```
setterm -blank 0 -powersave off < /dev/tty0 > /dev/tty0
```

**Update:**
Did you try the stuff that worked before with the previous version of Ubuntu on the same hardware? [Ubuntu server 9.10 freezes up after ~10 minutes](https://serverfault.com/questions/80520/ubuntu-server-9-10-freezes-up-after-10-minutes)

Comment: Yeah, I did try it. I'm seeing that my update-grub command is probably not running correctly.